# Problema con calculadora en Python

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

Buenas tengo un problema realizando una calculadora con el modulo de tkinter...., he construido una calculadora con una panel donde deberían escribirse los números de los botones que apriete pero no entiendo como podría hacer una función que haga tal cosa, se que se puede usar con funciones lambda pero cual seria la función??
adjunto a continuación el código que he realizado:

```
import tkinter
import parser

#ventana que abre la app
ventana=tkinter.Tk()
ventana.geometry("400x600")
ventana.title("Calculadora")


#pantalla de la calculadora
cuadrotext=tkinter.Entry(ventana,font=("arial",20,"bold"),width=22).grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=100,padx=20,pady=20)


#funcion para que imprima el numero-----aqui el problema----
i=0
def obtener_numero(n):
    n=int()


#botones de la calculadora.

boton1=tkinter.Button(ventana,text="1",command=lambda: obtener_numero(1),width=10,height=3).grid(row=5,column=0,padx=2)
boton2=tkinter.Button(ventana,text="2",width=10,height=3).grid(row=5,column=1,padx=2)
boton3=tkinter.Button(ventana,text="3",width=10,height=3).grid(row=5,column=2,padx=2)
boton4=tkinter.Button(ventana,text="4",width=10,height=3).grid(row=4,column=0)
boton5=tkinter.Button(ventana,text="5",width=10,height=3).grid(row=4,column=1)
boton6=tkinter.Button(ventana,text="6",width=10,height=3).grid(row=4,column=2)
boton7=tkinter.Button(ventana,text="7",width=10,height=3).grid(row=3,column=0)
boton8=tkinter.Button(ventana,text="8",width=10,height=3).grid(row=3,column=1)
boton9=tkinter.Button(ventana,text="9",width=10,height=3).grid(row=3,column=2)
boton0=tkinter.Button(ventana,text="0",width=10,height=3).grid(row=6,column=1)
botonP=tkinter.Button(ventana,text="=",width=10,height=3).grid(row=6,column=3)
botonAC=tkinter.Button(ventana,text="AC",width=10,height=3).grid(row=3,column=3)





ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: No queda muy claro lo que quieres hacer, que quieres que haga la función en cuestión?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otra opción es usar: partial

```
from functools import partial
```

Para pasar parámetros a una función desde un botón seria:

```
btn=Button(padre,text="btn", command=partial(tu_funcion, "tus parámetros"))
```

Entonces tu código se vería así:

```
from tkinter import  *
from functools import partial
import parser

#ventana que abre la app
ventana=Tk()
ventana.geometry("400x600")
ventana.title("Calculadora")

#pantalla de la calculadora
digito = StringVar()
cuadrotext=Entry(ventana,textvariable=digito,font=("arial",20,"bold"),width=22).grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=100,padx=20,pady=20)


def obtener_numero(n):
    digito.set(digito.get() + str(n))

#botones de la calculadora.

boton1=Button(ventana,text="1",width=10,height=3, command=partial(obtener_numero, 1)).grid(row=5,column=0,padx=2)
boton2=Button(ventana,text="2",width=10,height=3, command=partial(obtener_numero, 2)).grid(row=5,column=1,padx=2)
boton3=Button(ventana,text="3",width=10,height=3, command=partial(obtener_numero, 3)).grid(row=5,column=2,padx=2)
boton4=Button(ventana,text="4",width=10,height=3, command=partial(obtener_numero, 4)).grid(row=4,column=0)
boton5=Button(ventana,text="5",width=10,height=3, command=partial(obtener_numero, 5)).grid(row=4,column=1)
boton6=Button(ventana,text="6",width=10,height=3, command=partial(obtener_numero, 6)).grid(row=4,column=2)
boton7=Button(ventana,text="7",width=10,height=3, command=partial(obtener_numero, 7)).grid(row=3,column=0)
boton8=Button(ventana,text="8",width=10,height=3, command=partial(obtener_numero, 8)).grid(row=3,column=1)
boton9=Button(ventana,text="9",width=10,height=3, command=partial(obtener_numero, 9)).grid(row=3,column=2)
boton0=Button(ventana,text="0",width=10,height=3, command=partial(obtener_numero, 0)).grid(row=6,column=1)
botonP=Button(ventana,text="=",width=10,height=3, command=partial(obtener_numero, "=")).grid(row=6,column=3)
botonAC=Button(ventana,text="AC",width=10,height=3, command=partial(obtener_numero, "ac")).grid(row=3,column=3)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

En el caso de tu boton1, al pulsarlo, llama a la funcion partial(obtener_mumero, 1) (es lo que viene a continuación del parámetro "command")

A continuación un ejemplo

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

def callback():
    print "click!"

b = Button(master, text="OK", command=callback)
b.pack()

mainloop()
```

Al pulsar el botón Button, se activa la función callback()

Respecto a como invocar la función lambda, pues muy parecido a lo que tienes:

```
boton1=Button(ventana,text="1",width=10,height=3, command=lambda : partial(obtener_numero, 1)).grid(row=5,column=0,padx=2)
```